# Oxidation of ascorbic acid (Vitamin C)

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-oxidation

What would you suggest me to use for oxidation of vitamin C to dehydroascorbic acid instead of bromine water?

Comment: Iron(II), see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1319610310001389?via%3Dihub

Comment: Why not iodine? It is a standard and quantitative reaction.

Comment: Would you describe me procedure with iodine, M. Farooq? Thank you.

Comment: @Karsten Theis: Fe(III)?

Comment: @user55119 yes, ferric i e iron(III)